# Automating access to Bitbucket private repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I add `git pull origin master` to my auto-deploy script for a private repo, I'm given this error:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://someone@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
```

The SSH key for the server is already granted access to this Bitbucket account, so why would it produce this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your git pull command, I assume you are using `git clone https://someone@bitbucket.org/someone/repo.git` - this uses basic authentication over https not ssh keys. Using https to access a repo requires a username/password.

In order to use ssh key auth, you have to use ssh for your repo access with a command like: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:someone/repo.git`